# kprobe, function scheduling - processor lockup - Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've a function I wrote in order to run a given function on all processors. It works perfectly well in all cases except the following case:

When I try to use it within a kprobe that I registered.

Here's some code:

```
static DEFINE_MUTEX(entryMutex);
static struct kretprobe my_kprobe = {
.entry_handler = (kprobe_opcode_t *) NULL,
.handler = (kprobe_opcode_t *) process_entry_callback,
.maxactive = 1000,
.data_size = 0
};

static int driver_init(void)
{

    my_kprobe.kp.addr =      (kprobe_opcode_t*)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_execve");
    if ((ret = register_kretprobe(&my_kprobe)) < 0)
    return -1;
    return 0;
}

void foo(void* nothing)
{
     printk("In foo\n");
}

static int process_entry_callback(struct kretprobe_instance* instance, struct pt_regs* regs)

{
     mutex_lock(&entryMutex);

     for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) // assumes there are 4 processors
            run_func(foo, NULL, i);

     mutex_unlock(&entryMutex);
     return 0;
}  


void run_func_wrap(struct function_data* data)
{
    data->func(data->context);
    wake_up_process(data->waiting_task);
    *(data->condition) = TRUE; 
}

void run_func(SCHEDULED_FUNC func, void *context, int processor)
{
    struct function_data data;
    struct task_struct* th;
    BOOLEAN condition = FALSE;

    wait_queue_head_t queue;
init_waitqueue_head(&queue);

     data.func = func;
     data.waiting_task = current;
     data.context = context;
     data.condition = &condition;
     th = kthread_create(sched_func_wrap, &data, "th");
     kthread_bind(th, processor);
     wake_up_process(th);
     wait_event(queue, condition);
}
```

F

After the call to 'run_func' in process_entry_callback I can no longer run any programs. Every time I start a new program it just stuck. After a while I get 'processor lockup' warning in the system log.

I suspect that it has something to do with the IRQ levels.
Any suggestions ?

EDIT:

It also happens when using the following function:

```
smp_call_function_single
```

which can be found in smp.c @ the Linux kernel source code.

instead of my function:

```
run_func
```

Comment: `process_entry_callback()` should return 0 I think. Also, your code for running run_func on all processors is weird. Use `on_each_cpu()` (interrupt) or at least use `for_each_online_cpu()` instead of making assumptions.

Comment: @myaut Indeed. I believe not including a return statement would be undefined behavior.

Comment: There's a return 0 at the end of the function Ofc. Forgot to add it here.

Comment: And, please leave my run_func. It works perfectly fine if not used within a Kprobe callback. It seems that the 'sleeping' thread just never wakes up (When used inside a Kprobe).

Comment: Did you tried to use _SysRq_ + _T_ ? It will dump stack of all threads including yours. Also I think, you should add memory barrier like `smp_mb()` after setting `data->condition` (otherwise, `run_func` may check cached value) and put `data->condition` assignment before `wake_up_process` (or you may get race). Or use `completion` which is simpler than wait queues.

Comment: What is SysRQ + T ? could you explain pls?

Comment: @Rouki, It is key compination, SysRq is combined with PrintScreen. See more here: [w:Magic SysRq Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). Note that you may need to press Alt or Alt+Ctrl (see wikipidea article for details).